# "took out of" or "took from"

Tags: word-choice

Given the sentence:
**Helen pulled everything out of her suitcase.**

If I change this sentence to:

1. Helen **took** everything  **out of** her suitcase.
2. Helen **took** everything **from** her suitcase.

Which one has the same meaning as the original sentence?

- took out of, *or*
- took from.

Comment: Both choices are equivalent in meaning to the original.

Answer (score 1):

In nearly every case

> took out of

and

> took from

will have similar meanings of removing *something* from *somewhere*.

However, without additional context, "took out of" may be more neutral in connotation, whereas "took from" may imply removal from ownership of *someone else*.

> The money was *taken out of* her purse.
>   The money was *taken from* her purse.

Answer (score 0):

Its also a formal statement. What flows better when talking to people: `

> Helen took everything out of her her suitcase.

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).