# I will suck the blood out of your body or I will suck the blood from your body

Tags: prepositions

So friends what is the difference. A couple of days ago i was watching an Indian sitcom named Bhabi Ji Ghar  Par Hain. In it I saw  one of the main leads of the show saying it to the other person. I am sorry if the context is not clear. So please tell me which one is correct and if both are correct, what do they mean?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Both are possible.  "From" is more idiomatic.

Comment: Was the context that they were Vampires?

Comment: Yes  ASLUM, the male lead is pretending to be a Vampire.

Comment: *From* sounds more personal to me; *out of* sounds clinical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["took out of" or "took from"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105515/took-out-of-or-took-from)

Answer (score 2):

Both are "correct". They mean the same.

While appropriate for vampires, this isn't a common phrase for humans, but you could say

> I'm going to pull the plug (out of/from) the socket.

Both are correct and mean the same.